# How can I use Ajax with node.js with out using jQuery

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to use ajax with `node.js`, but it's like my server side node doesn't exist.

```html
<script>
        testmessage = () => {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("GET","../index.js", true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
</script>
```

This throws the following error:

> index.js not found

I'm hosting the site locally using `express` and `ejs`
My index.js file is a directory above

Comment: Where is your `index.js` file relative to where you're calling the `<script>` from?

Comment: i have changed where I've pointed it too multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I simply needed to send the request to `localhost:3000` because it IS the server, not some file under it.